# How can I run a mutually exclusive COUNT in Postgres?

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by, count

Say I have a (virtual) table like the following:

| firstColumn | secondColumn |
| --- | --- |
| fcVal1 | scVal1 |
| fcVal1 | scVal2 |
| fcVal2 | scVal1 |
| fcVal3 | scVal2 |

I want to find the following counts:

- Values in `firstColumn` that have both `scVal1` and `scVal2`
- Values in `firstColumn` that have only `scVal1`
- Values in `firstColumn` that have only `scVal2`

So the result would be:

| scVals | counts |
| --- | --- |
| scVal1 + scVal2 | 1 |
| scVal1 | 1 |
| scVal2 | 1 |

Note that these counts are mutually exclusive - `fcVal1` is *NOT* included in the counts for having only `scVal1` or `scVal2`

Preserving which `firstColumn` vals are associated with the `secondColumn` vals is not important, just the aggregate counts.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a self join to get a 'scVal1 + scVal2'  count

```
select count(distinct t1.firstColumn) n12
from tbl t1
join tbl t2 on t1.firstColumn = t2.firstColumn  
   and t1.secondColumn = 'scVal1' and t2.secondColumn = 'scVal2'
```

Alternatively, all three counts in a row

```
select 
   count(f1) n1,
   count(f2) n2,
   count(f1 + f2) n12
from (
  select
     max(case secondColumn when 'scVal1' then 1 end) f1,
     max(case secondColumn when 'scVal2' then 1 end) f2
  from tbl
  where secondColumn in ('scVal1', 'scVal2')
  group by firstColumn
) t
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are willing to hard code the combinations it's trivial to find out the counts. For example:

```
with
s as (
  select
    firstColumn,
    count(case when secondColumn = 'scVal1' then 1 end) as c1,
    count(case when secondColumn = 'scVal2' then 1 end) as c2
  from t
  group by firstColumn
)
select 'scVal1', count(*) from s where c1 > 0 and c2 = 0
union all select 'scVal2', count(*) from s where c1 = 0 and c2 > 0
union all select 'scVal1 + scVal2', count(*) from s where c1 > 0 and c2 > 0
```

Result:

```
 ?column?         count 
 ---------------- ----- 
 scVal1           1     
 scVal2           1     
 scVal1 + scVal2  1
```

See running example at [DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/bjYN3FLgMissZ2R5Ww2qFY/0).

A more generic solution where the combinations are not known from the beginning is also possible (though more complex) for low numbers of distinct values.